# Показ ячеек таблицы в зависимости от select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select, table

Доброго времени суток.
Имеется следующая динамическая таблица через php:

```
<?
                    if(!empty($_POST['ch'])) {
                        echo '<table id="rowclick5" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive cursor">
                            <tr style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">
                                <th></th>
                                <th><center>Наименование</center></th>
                                <th><center>Цена грн.</center></th>
                                <th><center>Качество деталей</center></th>
                            </tr>';
                        foreach ($_POST['ch'] as $item) {
                            $query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE `id` = '$item'");
                            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td><center><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></center></td>
                                    <td>'.$result['name'].'</td>
                                    <td id="priceor"><center>'.$result['priceor'].'</center></td>
                                    <td id="pricecopy"><center>'.$result['pricecopy'].'</center></td>
                                    <td>
                                    <center>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="selch">
                                                <option value="orig" selected>Оригинал</option>
                                                <option value="copy">Копия</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>';
                            }
                        }
                        echo '</table>';
                    } else {
                        echo 'Вы не выбрали ни одной позиции.';
                    }
                    ?>
```

Как мне сделать так, что-бы при select выборе допустим "Оригинал" - показывало в столбце "Цена" цену "оригинала" (priceor), а при выборе "Копия" - показывало только цену "копии" (pricecopy)? На разных наименованиях по своему должно показывать. Таблица динамическая и данные хранятся в БД. И желательно, что-бы ниже под таблицей выводилась "Общая сумма".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery подход, с минимальными изменениями в html:

```js
var $selch = $("select#selch"),
    closest_price,
    $prices = $(".price"),
    $current_sum = $("#current-sum");
    
    currentSum();

$selch.change(function() {

    closest_price = $(this).parent().parent("tr").find(".price");
    
    switch ( $(this).val() ) {
        case "0":
            closest_price.html(closest_price.data("price"));
            currentSum();
            break;
        case "1":
            closest_price.html(closest_price.data("price-copy"));
            currentSum();
            break;
         default:
            closest_price.html(closest_price.data("price"));
            currentSum();
            break;
    } 
    
});

function currentSum() {
  
    var sum = 0;
    
    $prices.each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
    })
    
    $current_sum.html(sum);
    
}
```

```css
table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Наименование</th>
        <th>Цена грн.</th>
        <th>Качество деталей</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="price" data-price="100" data-price-copy="99">100</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" id="selch">
                <option value="0" selected>Оригинал</option>
                <option value="1">Копия</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="price" data-price="200" data-price-copy="199">200</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" id="selch">
                <option value="0" selected>Оригинал</option>
                <option value="1">Копия</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="price" data-price="300" data-price-copy="299">300</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" id="selch">
                <option value="0" selected>Оригинал</option>
                <option value="1">Копия</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="3" id="current-sum"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня колонки формируются динамично с базы данных

Comment: Формируются в цыкле (и значения тоже)

Comment: точнее строки формируются

Comment: @Антон Александрович да, это видно из вопроса. надо всего лишь переложить мой пример на вашу структуру, изменения незначительны: цены раскладываются по data-атрибутам в td.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Comment: И еще вопросик: Как сделать автоматическое центрирование меняющихся значений? Через <center></center> не выходит.

Comment: @Антон Александрович css > td{ text-align:center }. А тег center c html5 не поддерживается.

Comment: Спасибо, и последний вопрос: Как мне сделать подсчет всех значений в ячейках "price"? Просто у мне подсчитывает только значения, которые записаны по дефолту через html, при смене значений - не скрипт не пересчитывает значения.

Comment: ну и соответственно вывести всю сумму в див, вот скрипт:

`function pluser(){
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(els).reduce( addMe, 0);
}

function addMe(p,c,i,a){
  return p + parseInt(c.textContent);
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '<div><strong>Итого: </strong>' + pluser() + ' грн.</div>';
}`

Comment: Добавил в ответ сумму по факту изменения, jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны реагировать на изменения `#selch` и в зависимости от того какая опция выбрана изменять значения а таблице